# How closed loop temperate control works in Ecigarette / Vaporisers

Tags: resistance, current-measurement, measurement, temperature, voltage-measurement

I have been reading about the use of heating elements made from Nickel and Stainless Steel in Ecigarettes. They are used as their resistance changes approximately linearly over the temperature range that it would be used.

If you can measure the resistance, you can approximate the temperature and control it. The thing I'm unsure about is how you can measure the resistance of the heating coil?

Is it possible to measure the resistance while the coil is on, or does it require the coil to be powered down briefly to measure it. I'd love to know what circuitry is needed between my microelectronic, and heating coil to measure the small change in resistance.

Any information would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is possible to measure the Tempco with another heat source such as a dry double boiler pot inside boiling water for 100'C. I.e. put coil with connections to an external DMM with heater inside a small metal cup in a pan of boiling water. verified with a thermometer

Comment: FYI, all a meter does to measure resistance is put a known voltage across the resistance, and measures the current. Alternatively, you could put a fixed current through it and measure the voltage that drops. In the case of your e-cig, the voltage (or current) that heats the coil does this for you. You just need to measure the volts and amps and compute the resistance.

Comment: If I am driving the heating element directly from a battery, using a MOSFET, I won't know the voltage being used, I won't know the current, and the change in resistance is very small, so I'll need accurate measurements.

I'm currently considering using a constant current sink/source IC, and an amplifying high resolution ADC to measure the voltage accross the coil, but I'll need to do this by briefly turning off the coil. The challenge here is getting a precise measurement and keeping the amount of PCB space down to a minimum. Can anyone see an issue with the approach I described?

Answer (score 2):

It's "ohmic", so if you know the voltage across it and the current flowing through it, you know its resistance.

Because the change is quite small, you need to be careful with the measurement. You probably should use four-wire "Kelvin" measurement for the voltage across the element, and to measure the current you need *another* resistor of a known, small value called a *shunt*. And you need to make sure that its temperature does not affect the reading too much.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done via 4wires.

A power source will force current through the load and two "non-current" carrying wires close to the actual load are used to sense the load voltage.

With an additional sense resistor to measure actual current flow you will know load I and load V ==> Load R

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOJ0IV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>